# Percent Complete functionality in Oracle Apps Project module

Tags: projects, oracle-apps

I am talking about Oracle Apps Projects module.

In Projects module there is a Project Status Inquiry which includes 
Percent Complete functionality.   I want information regarding this functionality. 
Is it updated automatically?  Does it require us to run any pre-requisites?

Please give me information about what this function does.

thanks
Nil

Comment: please try a little harder formulating your question. as it is now, it is incomprehensible and will probably be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: As this is a question about using the Projects module in Oracle e-Business Suite it really belongs on SuperUser.  However, I suspect you're more likely to get an answer from your cross-posting at the OTN EBS forum.  However, as Projects isn't a widely-used component I'm afraid you may well not get any answer at all.